# No value given for one or more required parameters visual basic error

Tags: vba, vb6

This error is appearing in following line of the vb code

```
 rs.Open "select * From Reservation where [table_number]=tablenumber.text and booking_date=bookingdate.Text", cn, adOpenStatic, adLockPessimistic
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's a problem with your SQL query. The reason for the message is that the SQL parser can't identify a token in your SQL query and interprets it as a parameter for which you need to provide a value.

So, you either mistyped some of your field or table names, or you created your SQL the wrong way. I suppose the latter and it should read

```
 rs.Open "select * From Reservation where [table_number] = " & tablenumber.text & " and booking_date=" & bookingdate.Text, cn, adOpenStatic, adLockPessimistic
```

because `tablenumber` and `bookingdate` are very likely form controls.

The above query won't work out of the box as you need to use the correct data types for the SQL query which I cannot infer based on your sparse information.

Answer (score 1):

If you are `INSERT`ing values in TABLE - dont miss enclosing it in single quotes, like
`' " & text1.text & " '`

example:

```
INSERT into [TABLE NAME]([Purchase Order Status]) values(' " & text1.text & " ')
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adding () around the selection criteria:

```
rs.Open "select * From Reservation where ( [table_number]=tablenumber.text and booking_date=bookingdate.Text )"
```