# Error No value given for one or more required parameters with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting "No value given for one or more required parameters", I am new in Excel VBA, Please suggest what is wrong with the query, Below is the code I am using to get the value from a access data based and I want to have the table name and the table column name on runtime.

```
Dim con As ADODB.Connection

Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset

Dim name As String

Dim count As Integer

Dim FindString As String

Dim FindString1 As String

Dim SQLQuery As String

FindString = InputBox("Enter the table name")

FindString1 = InputBox("Enter search value")

count = 4

Dim strConn As String

Set con = New ADODB.Connectioncon.Mode = adModeReadWrite

If con.State = adStateClosed Then
   strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & "databasepath\Database3.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"

   con.ConnectionString = strConn
   con.Open
   Set rs.ActiveConnection = con
End If


SQLQuery = "select * from " & FindString & " where " & FindString & ".[LOGO] ='" & FindString1 & "'"
```

rs.Open SQLQuery

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6034959/open-recordset-in-access-2003-2007

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675544%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Can you please post your complete code? Or at least the `Sub`routine where this snippet belongs? :)

Comment: I have placed the code in the post.. please check..

Answer (score -1):

Looks like a problem with this SQL query.

`"select * from " & FindString & " where [Resolution] = '" & FindString1 & "'"`

I would suggest to make an extra step like this.

```
Dim SQLQuery as String
SQLQuery = "select * from [" & FindString & "] where [Resolution] = '" & FindString1 & "'"
rs.Open SQLQuery
```

Maybe you can have a look at this solution too.

[No value given for one or more required parameters visual basic error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17651091/no-value-given-for-one-or-more-required-parameters-visual-basic-error)

Comment: Michael, Thanks for the answer, but still I am getting the same error by using the way you suggested.